# ARKit error after changing robot.usdz color

Tags: ios, xcode, arkit, usdz

I'm trying to change the color of the robot.usdz supplied in the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/capturing_body_motion_in_3d sample project.

When I run the default project, it works fine. However, if I select part of the model in Xcode and change the color using the Material Inspector:

[image]

When I run the app I get these errors:

- Created entity character does not contain supplied joint name: left_toes_joint.
- Cannot get joint count for non-character entity.
- Unable to load model: The operation couldn’t be completed.

I'm not sure is there a step I'm missing in changing the color, or whether there's something else going on?